# Scrape a website in nodeJS which requires authorization, when authorization is provided in a get request?

Tags: node.js, api, http, web-scraping

I am scraping a webSite in nodejs for getting information from it (using http Parsing).
The website requires basic auth username and password to sign in.
I have to write an API that will do web scraping of that website. I will be providing basic Auth - username, and password in the postman and will be firing my API from postman only.

I don't want to hardcode username and password inside my code. I will be getting the credentials from postman request only.

So how do I tackle this while writing the API?
How I will be using the username and password given in postman?

Comment: Are you sure it's basic auth? I if so you can pass it in the url

Answer (score 0):

Using NodeJS you can pass in the user ID and password as headers:

```
var request = require('request'),
    username = "john",
    password = "1234",
    url = "http://www.example.com",
    auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");

request(
{
    url : url,
    headers : {
        "Authorization" : auth
    }
},
    function (error, response, body) {
        // Do scraping here
    }
);
```

If the scraping is complex or there are interactive login screens I would look at puppeteer which is a good framework for this kind of stuff.

Comment: I don't want to hardcode username and password inside my ocde, I will be getting usename and password form API request / postman only.  So how would I be making request to website in that case?

Comment: Anything you do in postman you can also do in code, so you would make a call to the service that gives you the id and password, and then feed that into a second request. If you have a github repo I could give more concrete advice. Be careful not to expose your ID and password though!

Comment: Go to this URL - http://159.89.165.152/                                                                     You will see a pop up appears where you put username and password.I want to scrap this website. In postman I will be providing username and password under basic auth. How should I write my API that the username and password provided in postman will be utilized in the API that I write in my nodejs app? Thanks.

Comment: @Daviid plz help.

Comment: Copy and paste what you put into postman (except your ID/password) and I'll help

Comment: In postman I am just firing an API to my server which I am running on localhost localhost:3000/startKafkaLagMonitoring . And I am providing the url of web page which I will be scrapping in req.body.url and I am sending username and password in basic authorization . Thanks.